# how can I connect to a postgresql database from external psycopg2.connect?

Tags: python, postgresql

I would like to connect to a postgresql database using python from  a different server. 
I triyed this :

```
conn_string = "host=192.168.1.1 dbname='"+db7+"' user='user' password='"+pw7+"'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

but I get the error:

```
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "database" does not exist
```

Comment: `'"+db7+"'` is a syntax error ? whats your real db name ?

Comment: db7='database' its a variable

Comment: so why you are using `+` and `"` ?

Comment: conn_string="....dbname='"+db7+"'...."   to add the ' ' to the variable

Comment: you dont need + to add ! checkout the answer

Answer (score 1):

Remove unnecessary quotes in the syntax.

Follow this structure.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host = "localhost",database="ur_database_name", user="db_user", password="your_password")
```

Example.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host = "localhost",database="studentesdb", user="postgres", password="admin")
```

Comment: psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "192.168.1.1" and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?